# Ubuntu unable to reboot

Tags: boot, grub2, syslinux

I am very new to Ubuntu/Linux system. After installing systems and a few softwares I try to reboot. But the message below shows up and I can't do nothing about it.

[image]

It just keeps blinking on my screen and there is nothing I can do about it.

I tried somethings on the internet but nothing helps.

I tried reinstall from a rebootbale usb, but it shows that start_img is missing. I can get into grub shell, but nothing much can be done there.

Can anyone please tell me how I can solve this? Im really stucking here right now.

Comment: Looks like you chose LVM https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm instead of normal ext4 disk partitioning in the 'Allocate disk space' step of installation. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 is the best tutorial to follow when installing Ubuntu.